# Preserving Polymorphic Types in a WCF Service using JSON

Tags: c#, wcf, json, polymorphism

I have a C# WCF service using a webHttpBinding endpoint that will receive and return data in JSON format. The data to send/receive needs to use a polymorphic type so that data of different types can be exchanged in the same "data packet". I have the following data model:

```
[DataContract]
public class DataPacket
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<DataEvent> DataEvents { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(IntEvent))]
[KnownType(typeof(BoolEvent))]
public class DataEvent
{
    [DataMember]
    public ulong Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("DataEvent: {0}, {1}", Id, Timestamp);
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class IntEvent : DataEvent
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("IntEvent: {0}, {1}, {2}", Id, Timestamp, Value);
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class BoolEvent : DataEvent
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("BoolEvent: {0}, {1}, {2}", Id, Timestamp, Value);
    }
}
```

My service will send/receive the sub-type events (IntEvent, BoolEvent etc.) in a single data packet, as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetExampleDataEvents")]
    DataPacket GetExampleDataEvents();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "SubmitDataEvents", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void SubmitDataEvents(DataPacket dataPacket);
}

public class DataService : IDataService
{
    public DataPacket GetExampleDataEvents()
    {
        return new DataPacket {
            DataEvents = new List<DataEvent>
            {
                new IntEvent  { Id = 12345, Timestamp = DateTime.Now, Value = 5 },
                new BoolEvent { Id = 45678, Timestamp = DateTime.Now, Value = true }
            }
        };
    }

    public void SubmitDataEvents(DataPacket dataPacket)
    {
        int i = dataPacket.DataEvents.Count; //dataPacket contains 2 events, but both are type DataEvent instead of IntEvent and BoolEvent
        IntEvent intEvent = dataPacket.DataEvents[0] as IntEvent;
        Console.WriteLine(intEvent.Value); //null pointer as intEvent is null since the cast failed
    }
}
```

When I submit my packet to the `SubmitDataEvents` method though, I get `DataEvent` types and trying to cast them back to their base types (just for testing purposes) results in an `InvalidCastException`. My packet is:

```
POST http://localhost:4965/DataService.svc/SubmitDataEvents HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:4965
Content-Type: text/json
Content-Length: 340

{
    "DataEvents": [{
        "__type": "IntEvent:#WcfTest.Data",
        "Id": 12345,
        "Timestamp": "\/Date(1324905383689+0000)\/",
        "Value": 5
    }, {
        "__type": "BoolEvent:#WcfTest.Data",
        "Id": 45678,
        "Timestamp": "\/Date(1324905383689+0000)\/",
        "Value": true
    }]
}
```

Apologies for the long post, but is there anything I can do to preserve the base types of each object? I thought adding the type hint to the JSON and the KnownType attributes to `DataEvent` would allow me to preserve the types - but it doesn't seem to work.

**Edit**: If I send the request to `SubmitDataEvents` in XML format (with `Content-Type: text/xml` instead of `text/json`) then the `List<DataEvent> DataEvents` does contain the sub-types instead of the super-type. As soon as I set the request to `text/json` and send the above packet then I only get the super-type and I can't cast them to the sub-type. My XML request body is:

```
<ArrayOfDataEvent xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfTest.Data">
  <DataEvent i:type="IntEvent" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Id>12345</Id>
    <Timestamp>1999-05-31T11:20:00</Timestamp>
    <Value>5</Value>
  </DataEvent>
  <DataEvent i:type="BoolEvent" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Id>56789</Id>
    <Timestamp>1999-05-31T11:20:00</Timestamp>
    <Value>true</Value>
  </DataEvent>
</ArrayOfDataEvent>
```

**Edit 2**: Updated service description after Pavel's comments below. This still doesn't work when sending the JSON packet in Fiddler2. I just get a `List` containing `DataEvent` instead of `IntEvent` and `BoolEvent`.

**Edit 3**: As Pavel suggested, here is the output from `System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()`. Looks OK to me.

```
<root type="object">
    <DataEvents type="array">
        <item type="object">
            <__type type="string">IntEvent:#WcfTest.Data</__type> 
            <Id type="number">12345</Id> 
            <Timestamp type="string">/Date(1324905383689+0000)/</Timestamp> 
            <Value type="number">5</Value> 
        </item>
        <item type="object">
            <__type type="string">BoolEvent:#WcfTest.Data</__type> 
            <Id type="number">45678</Id> 
            <Timestamp type="string">/Date(1324905383689+0000)/</Timestamp> 
            <Value type="boolean">true</Value> 
        </item>
    </DataEvents>
</root>
```

When tracing the deserialization of the packet, I get the following messages in the trace:

```
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Verbose">
    <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/System.Runtime.Serialization.ElementIgnored.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
    <Description>An unrecognized element was encountered in the XML during deserialization which was ignored.</Description>
    <AppDomain>1c7ccc3b-4-129695001952729398</AppDomain>
    <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/StringTraceRecord">
        <Element>:__type</Element>
    </ExtendedData>
</TraceRecord>
```

This message is repeated 4 times (twice with `__type` as the element and twice with `Value`). Looks like the type hinting information is being ignored then the `Value` elements are ignored as the packet is deserialized to `DataEvent` instead of `IntEvent`/`BoolEvent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Pavel Gatilov, I've now found the solution to this problem. I'll add it as separate answer here for anyone who may be caught out by this in future.

The problem is that the JSON deserializer doesn't seem to be very accepting of whitespace. The data in the packet that I was sending was "pretty printed" with line breaks and spaces to make it more readable. However, when this packet was deserialized, this meant that when looking for the `"__type"` hint, the JSON deserializer was looking at the wrong part of the packet. This meant that the type hint was missed and the packet was deserialized as the wrong type.

The following packet works correctly:

```
POST http://localhost:6463/DataService.svc/SubmitDataEvents HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: text/json
Host: localhost:6463
Content-Length: 233

{"DataEvents":[{"__type":"IntEvent:#WebApplication1","Id":12345,"Timestamp":"\/Date(1324905383689+0000)\/","IntValue":5},{"__type":"BoolEvent:#WebApplication1","Id":45678,"Timestamp":"\/Date(1324905383689+0000)\/","BoolValue":true}]}
```

However, this packet doesn't work:

```
POST http://localhost:6463/DataService.svc/SubmitDataEvents HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: text/json
Host: localhost:6463
Content-Length: 343

{
    "DataEvents": [{
        "__type": "IntEvent:#WebApplication1",
        "Id": 12345,
        "Timestamp": "\/Date(1324905383689+0000)\/",
        "IntValue": 5
    }, {
        "__type": "BoolEvent:#WebApplication1",
        "Id": 45678,
        "Timestamp": "\/Date(1324905383689+0000)\/",
        "BoolValue": true
    }]
}
```

These packets are exactly the same apart from the line breaks and spaces.

Comment: Wow... Glad to know your issue has been resolved. However, the formatted JSON worked fine for me, I've always copy-pasted it to Fiddler and had no issues. I do believe that either you have not installed all the updates for the .NET framework, or the latest version has a weird bug related to whitespace characters processing. I'm completely embarassed.

Comment: Don't be embarrassed at all, I never would've found that without your help. The only way I found out was by debugging the WCF source code that you posted above. I noticed that the value for `offset` was always too low and happened to notice that the inclusion of the `\r` and `\n` characters in the message buffer was throwing off the offset calculation somehow. I may post another question to see if anyone knows why the whitespace interferes with the parsing, as I'd like the flexibility of it being included or not.

Comment: Oh, that should've been 'confused' rather than 'embarassed' :). By the way, I have found the description of a similar issue [in this article](http://blog.js-development.com/2010/05/n-will-break-your-json-jquery-wcf.html).

Answer (score 3):

Whenever dealing with serialization, try to first serialize an object graph to see the serialized string format. Then use the format to produce correct serialized strings.

Your packet is incorrect. The correct one is:

```
POST http://localhost:47440/Service1.svc/SubmitDataEvents HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:47440
Content-Length: 211
Content-Type: text/json

[
  {
    "__type":"IntEvent:#WcfTest.Data",
    "Id":12345,
    "Timestamp":"\/Date(1324757832735+0700)\/",
    "Value":5
  },
  {
    "__type":"BoolEvent:#WcfTest.Data",
    "Id":45678,
    "Timestamp":"\/Date(1324757832736+0700)\/",
    "Value":true
  }
]
```

Note the `Content-Type` header also.

I've tried it with your code and it works perfectly (well, I've removed the `Console.WriteLine` and tested in debugger). All the class hierarchy is fine, all objects can be cast to their types. It works.

**UPDATE**

The JSON you've posted works with the following code:

```
[DataContract]
public class SomeClass
{
  [DataMember]
  public List<DataEvent> dataEvents { get; set; }
}

...

[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataService
{
  ...

  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "SubmitDataEvents")]
  void SubmitDataEvents(SomeClass parameter);
}
```

Note that another high-level node is added to the object tree.

And again, it works fine with inheritance.

If the problem still remains, please post the code that you use to invoke the service, as well as exception details you get.

**UPDATE 2**

How strange... It works on my machine.

I use .NET 4 and VS2010 with the latest updates on Win7 x64.

I take your service contract, implementation and data contracts. I host them in a web application under Cassini. I have the following web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- excluded for brevity -->
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <!-- excluded for brevity -->
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="WebApplication1.DataService">
        <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WebApplication1.IDataService"/>
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"
           binding="webHttpBinding"
           contract="WebApplication1.IDataService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Now I make the following POST by Fiddler2 (important: I've renamed the namespace of the derived types to match my case):

```
POST http://localhost:47440/Service1.svc/SubmitDataEvents HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: text/json
Host: localhost:47440
Content-Length: 336

{
    "DataEvents": [{
        "__type": "IntEvent:#WebApplication1",
        "Id": 12345,
        "Timestamp": "\/Date(1324905383689+0000)\/",
        "Value": 5
    }, {
        "__type": "BoolEvent:#WebApplication1",
        "Id": 45678,
        "Timestamp": "\/Date(1324905383689+0000)\/",
        "Value": true
    }]
}
```

Then I have the following code in the service implementation:

```
public void SubmitDataEvents(DataPacket parameter)
{
  foreach (DataEvent dataEvent in parameter.DataEvents)
  {
    var message = dataEvent.ToString();
    Debug.WriteLine(message);
  }
}
```

Note that debugger shows the items details as `DataEvent`s, but string representations and the first item in the details clearly show that all sub-types have been deserialized well:
[image: Debugger screenshot]

And debug output contains the following after I hit the method:

```
IntEvent: 12345, 26.12.2011 20:16:23, 5
BoolEvent: 45678, 26.12.2011 20:16:23, True
```

I've also tried running it under the IIS (on Win7) and everything works fine too.

I've had only the base type deserialized after I corrupted the packet by deleting one underscore from the `__type` field name. If I modify the value of `__type`, the call will crash during deserialization, it won't hit the service.

Here is what you could try:

1. Make sure you don't have any debug messages, exceptions, etc (check Debug Output).
2. Create a new clean web application solution, paste the required code and test if it works there. If it does, then your original project must have some weird configuration settings.
3. In debugger, analyze `System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()` in the Watch window. It will contain the XML message translated from your JSON. Check if it is correct.
4. Check if you have any pending updates for .NET.
5. Try [tracing WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx). Although it doesn't seem to emit any warnings for messages with wrong `__type` field name, it may happen that it will show you some hints for your issues reasons.

**My RequestMessage**

Seems like here is the track of the issue: while you have `__type` as element, I have it as attribute. Supposedly, your WCF assemblies have a bug in JSON to XML translation

```
<root type="object">
  <DataEvents type="array">
    <item type="object" __type="IntEvent:#WebApplication1">
      <Id type="number">12345</Id>
      <Timestamp type="string">/Date(1324905383689+0000)/</Timestamp>
      <Value type="number">5</Value>
    </item>
    <item type="object" __type="BoolEvent:#WebApplication1">
      <Id type="number">45678</Id>
      <Timestamp type="string">/Date(1324905383689+0000)/</Timestamp>
      <Value type="boolean">true</Value>
    </item>
  </DataEvents>
</root>
```

I've found the place where `__type` is processed. Here it is:

```
// from System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonReader, System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0
void ReadServerTypeAttribute(bool consumedObjectChar)
{
  int offset;
  int offsetMax; 
  int correction = consumedObjectChar ? -1 : 0;
  byte[] buffer = BufferReader.GetBuffer(9 + correction, out offset, out offsetMax); 
  if (offset + 9 + correction <= offsetMax) 
  {
    if (buffer[offset + correction + 1] == (byte) '\"' && 
        buffer[offset + correction + 2] == (byte) '_' &&
        buffer[offset + correction + 3] == (byte) '_' &&
        buffer[offset + correction + 4] == (byte) 't' &&
        buffer[offset + correction + 5] == (byte) 'y' && 
        buffer[offset + correction + 6] == (byte) 'p' &&
        buffer[offset + correction + 7] == (byte) 'e' && 
        buffer[offset + correction + 8] == (byte) '\"') 
    {
      // It's attribute!
      XmlAttributeNode attribute = AddAttribute(); 
      // the rest is omitted for brevity
    } 
  } 
}
```

I've tried to find the place where the attribute is used to determine the deserialized type, but to no luck.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The packet that I was sending in was generated by calling `GetExampleDataEvents()` first, then changing the name in the JSON to `dataEvents`. I didn't include the HTTP headers but I did as you did and sent in the packet using Fiddler2 (including the `Content-Type: text/json`.

Comment: That's very strange, because the JSON I've posted is **exactly** the JSON returned by `GetExampleDataEvents()` **without any modifications**. Have you tried it? Did it work? If it did, why are you trying to change it? When I tried your JSON, I got empty list, because it requires another class which would contain the list.

Comment: I've updated the problem description with your recommendations above. Still no luck I'm afraid!

Comment: @AdamRodger I've updated my answer to clearly show what I do to test your code. I've also added some hints on further troubleshooting. In fact, I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: I've literally copied and pasted all the code from this page into a new solution (fixing namespaces etc.) and it still doesn't work. In your screenshot of the debugger where it shows an `IntEvent` and `BoolEvent`, both of mine show as `DataEvent`. I'll try and do a WCF trace as you recommend. In the meantime, is there any way you can send me your solution so I can try to spot the difference?