# C# WCF REST Service interprets received type as base class

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, types

I have a C# WCF REST service running, which works fine and dandy. However, at some point, I'm executing a PUT request to update a class. The (trimmed) JSON that I send to the WCF service:

```
{
    "admin": {
        "EntityName": "TestAdmin_xCCg_edited",
        "EntityParent": {
            "TenantBankAccountNr": "1234567",
            "TenantCity": "Amsterdam",
            "TenantCountry": "Holland",
            "TenantGroup": null,
            "TenantNr": "1P",
            "TenantPrefix": "MB",
            "TenantStreet": "DeStraatStraat",
            "TenantStreetNr": "38",
            "TenantVatNr": "1234",
            "TenantZipcode": "1442",
            "AdSynced": false,
            "CreatedByUser": null,
            "CreationDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+01:00",
            "EntityName": "Partner_NXfL",
            "EntityParent": {
                "AdSynced": false,
                "CreatedByUser": "Unknown",
                "CreationDate": "2013-02-13T15:59:28+01:00",
                "EntityName": "Veliq",
                "EntityParent": null,
                "EntityType": 2,
                "EntityUID": "172de253-b71d-44ef-ae52-94c21ca957ba",
                "GroupMemberships": null,
                "LazyProperties": [
                    "EntityParent",
                    "GroupMemberships"
                ],
                "MappedIdentifier": null,
                "MappedSystem": null,
                "ModificationDate": "2013-02-13T15:59:28+01:00",
                "ModifiedByUser": "Unknown"
            },
            "EntityType": 2,
            "EntityUID": "2a15f1ea-fefb-408f-9c88-abcb392ad9c3",
            "GroupMemberships": null,
            "LazyProperties": [
                "EntityParent",
                "GroupMemberships",
                "TenantGroup"
            ],
            "MappedIdentifier": null,
            "MappedSystem": null,
            "ModificationDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+01:00",
            "ModifiedByUser": null
        },
        "EntityType": 6,
        "EntityUID": "70bc26fc-f50d-4e11-8b04-983b1c5978c0",
    }
}
```

The base object ("admin" object, of type WSAdmin) gets sent over fine, but the problem is that the EntityParent field is not. It is of WSPartner type (which extends WSTenant which extends WSEntity), but the data received by the server is of WSEntity type. That means it truncates a lot of data it really shouldn't. How could I resolve this issue? Manually adding the "__type" : "WSPartner:#MOBIWS" flag didn't work, it throws the exception about ServiceKnownType etc. I've added all those types already and they work.

I've also seen an issue about [whitespace giving errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625803/preserving-polymorphic-types-in-a-wcf-service-using-json), but that wasn't the issue for me (I was sending non-prettified JSON). Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to tell WCF about your types using the ServiceKnownType attribute. I would recommend doing this programmatically (using reflection if necessary), rather than hardcoding the types in the attribute. This SO question explains how:

[How do you configure WCF known types programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771560/how-do-you-configure-wcf-known-types-programmatically)

Comment: I'm not sure if that will solve the issue .. but I'll take a look at it in a bit thank you!

Comment: If your EntityParent field is a WSEntity type (which it sounds like it is), then by default WCF will return WSEntity even if the real type being returned by an operation is one that inherits from WSEntity. The ServiceKnownType attribute lets you provide WCF with list of types to use in addition to what is discovered from the fields declared type.

Comment: Yeah I know about that, but that doesn't explain why it doesn't work when I have specified the WSPartner in the ServiceKnowntype and it works when the root object is of WSPartner (which is now WSAdmin). I'm currently looking at the programmatically adding the ServiceKnownTypes, I'll let you know if that works!

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work! Either way, thanks for that, helped me get rid of the huge list of ServiceKnownType attributes (100+) I had going. And new ones should be automatically added as well, so that's only a major improvement.