# Accepting different types for WCF object parameter

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I'd like to be able to accept all kind of parameters for a WCF call. The actual signature is something like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Message
{
    private Message() {}

    public static Message Create(MessageTypeEnum type, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return new Message {MessageType = type, Parameters = parameters};
    }

    [DataMember]
    public MessageTypeEnum MessageType { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public object[] Parameters { get; private set; }
}


public void SendMessage(Message message)
{
   var receivers = GetReceiversByMessageType(Message.MessageType);
   foreach(var receiver in receivers)
   {
      var template = GetMessage(type, receiver.Locale)
      var text = string.Format(template, receiver.Locale, Message.Parameters);
      SendMessage(receiver.Address, text);
   }
}
```

The message call works for simple types, like integers, dates and strings.
However, I'd like to be able to also send tuples and arrays of arrays.
(I'm actually using a different formatting method supporting this)

My WCF call throws (de)serialization exceptions. Is there a trick to allow for different types?

*edit*

Some context:

As WCF is used to communicate between our web servers and our business logic servers, this is kind of a requirement. There should always be a good reasons to deviate from standards, and I don't think a simple alerter qualifies.

In our actual solution, a seperate Message object is used. I can change both the client and the server side of how the message is serialized. I cannot change the message creation method, as is it is used at too many places.

This works:

```
var msg = Message.Create(MessageTypeEnum.InvalidName, "Petr");
Clients.MessageClient(c => c.SendMessage(msg));
```

this doesn't:

```
var msg = Message.Create(MessageTypeEnum.InvalidNames, new[] {"Petr", "Jann"};
Clients.MessageClient(c => c.SendMessage(msg));
```

Comment: I'm not sure WCF is the best choice here, it uses the [data contract serializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for both XML and JSON and so requires an implicit or explicit [data contract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Web API might be a better choice, you can [send and receive raw JSON and XML](http://bizcoder.com/posting-raw-json-to-web-api) as, respectively, a `JToken` or `XElement`.

Comment: If you must use WCF, how flexible are you in the your sending format?  WCF does support [type hints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625803/preserving-polymorphic-types-in-a-wcf-service-using-json) for both JSON and XML but you must format your message precisely on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with to make the message serialize and deserialize. Note that the deserialized version has lost its complex types, and all collections have been converted to arrays. That's good enough for my purposes.

```
[DataContract]
public class Message
{
    public static Message Create(MessageTypeEnum type, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return new Message {MessageType = type, Parameters = parameters};
    }

    [DataMember]
    public MessageTypeEnum MessageType { get; set; }

    public IList<object> Parameters { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IList<string> SerializedParameters
    {
        get { return Parameters.Select(JsonConvert.SerializeObject).ToArray(); }
        set { Parameters = value.Select(DeserializeObject).ToArray(); }
    }

    private object DeserializeObject(string json)
    {
        return ReplaceArrays(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json));
    }

    private object ReplaceArrays(object obj)
    {
        var dictionary = obj as IDictionary<string, JToken>;
        if (dictionary != null) return dictionary.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => ReplaceArrays(kvp.Value));
        var collection = obj as JArray;
        if (collection != null) return collection.Cast<object>().Select(ReplaceArrays).ToArray();
        var jValue = obj as JValue;
        if (jValue != null) return jValue.Value;
        return obj;
    }
}
```

(...)

```
public void SendMessage(Message message)
{
   var receivers = GetReceiversByMessageType(Message.MessageType);
   foreach(var receiver in receivers)
   {
      var template = GetMessage(type, receiver.Locale)
      var text = string.Format(template, receiver.Locale, Message.Parameters);
      SendMessage(receiver.Address, text);
   }
}
```